# Makefile project in Eclipse can be run but cannot be debug, why?

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging

I have imported an "existing code as makefile project" project in eclipse. It can be normally built and run, but Eclipse reported numerous errors and cannot debug.

I have tried the following ways:

1. add "/usr/include" in Paths and Symbols.
2. Run C/C++ code analysis.
3. C/C++ index ==> Rebuild and Freshen all files.
   But they all make no difference.

The detail information about my question is as follows:
Most of the errors are **"Symbol xxx could not be resolved"** as well as several head files could not be resolved, they are `<stdarg.h>`, `<sys/types.h>`, `<sys/wait.h>` and `<sys/stat.h>`. However, I can build and run it normally. But when I debug it, Eclipse cannot find the `main()` function as following shows:
[the information in Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUvC5.png)

Is there anybody encountered the same questions? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you import a project in eclipse from an existing `Makefile`, you depend on the compiler options used to build the executable to generate the runnable.  If you don't put debug options when compiling, probably you'll not be able to source debug the executable.  You probably will need a special target or some options to pass to the `make` command issued by eclipse to make your build include the necessary `-g` and `-O0` options to make the executable debuggable.

Answer (score 0):

Are you confident that the project is building correctly? In Project Properties, on C/C++ Build dialog, make sure you have specified correct build directory. It should be the directory in which your makefile is present. Please verify, the build command generates .elf file for your project. Can you share your makefile?

[Sorry, this response doesn't fit as an answer but posting as an answer because I am a new user and can't post comments on other's posts]